# Confused about notation in graph

Tags: graph-theory, notation

Is anyone familiar with the notation on the graph below: [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onS6e.png)

Comment: Edges which do not intersect thanks to moving in the third dimension

Comment: Thank you. Thought it was something mysterious

Comment: It gives edge trolls a place to hide.